# Characteristics for a transport equation with discontinuous coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

Consider the transport equation on $[0,T] \times \mathbb{R}$: $$\partial_{t}u+ q(t,x)\partial_{x}u=0$$ where the initial data $u(0, \cdot) = u_{0}(\cdot)$ is Lipschitz continuous in space and time and $q(t,x) = sgn(x).$

**Goal:** Construct a continuous solution using the method of characteristics.

**Attempt:** The method of characteristics tells us that we need to solve the system
$$\begin{aligned}
&\frac{dt}{ds}=1,~ t(0) = 0, \\
&\frac{dx}{ds}=q,~ x(0) = \tau, \\
&\frac{du}{ds}=0,~ u(0)= u_{0}(\tau).
\end{aligned}$$
Solving gives us that the set of characteristic lines is given by the set $$ \Gamma = \{ x-sgn(x)t = \tau  ~| ~\tau \in \mathbb{R}\}. $$ So, wherever the characteristics are defined, the solution is given by $$u(t,x) = u_{0}(x - sgn(x)t). $$ From here, I am confused on how to arrive at the final solution which should be

$$u(x,t)= \begin{cases}
u_{0}(x-tsgn(x)) & \text{ if } t \leq |x|, \\
h(t-|x|) & \text{ if } t \geq |x|.
\end{cases}$$ where $h \in Lip[0,T]$ is such that $h(0) = u_{0}(0)$.

Sketching the characteristics is the confusing part because the characteristic lines are themselves discontinuous! We have a bunch of disjoint lines of gradient $\pm 1$  which I am unsure how to interpret. Is the solution really constant along these discontinuous lines? How can we arrive at the final solution?

I would appreciate any help.

**Some more thoughts:**
The only continuous characteristic is given by $t = |x|$. I sketched a few of these characteristic lines (I took $\tau = 0, -1, 1, 2$) and saw that below $t=|x|$ we have some intersection, so I guess the solution is not defined there. One way to define the solution in this region $t < |x|$ in a continuous way is to join together with a continuous function $h$ which agrees with the value of $u_{0}$ along $t=|x|$. This would explain the final answer. But I am unsure if these ramblings are true because, well, the characteristics look super weird and I don't know if the method of characteristics is even valid in such a scenario.

Comment: You didn't write the Lagrange-Charpit equations properly; you should have had $\partial_s(t,x,u) = (1,0,-q)$.

Comment: @Abezhiko there was a typo in the original equation I corrected it now